# How do I run poetry install in a subprocess without reference to the current virtualenv?

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv, python-poetry

I am writing some auto setup code in a command line tool that we have.
This command line tool is installed with poetry, so when someone is invoking the command line tool, it is from within a virtual environment setup by poetry.

The command I am trying to invoke is `poetry install` for *another directory*.
I want this command to create a new virtualenv for the other directory.

What I am currently doing is

```py
import subprocess

other_directory = "/some/path"

subprocess.run([f"cd {other_directory} && poetry install && poetry env info"], cwd=other_directory, shell=True, check=True)
```

But that always installs the dependencies from the other repo into the virtualenv that I am using to run this script. I have also tried to use the path to the system poetry instead of the one in the virtualenv, but that doesn't work either.
The `poetry env info` command always outputs the info for the current virtualenv:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.10.9
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /home/veith/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-cli-tool-Qe2jDmlM-py3.10
Executable:     /home/veith/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-cli-tool-Qe2jDmlM-py3.10/bin/python
Valid:          True
```

And if I manually `cd` to the other directory and run `poetry env info`, it always shows that no virtualenv is set up:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.10.9
Implementation: CPython
Path:           NA
Executable:     NA
```

The output I am looking for here would be:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.10.9
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /home/veith/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-other-directory-HASH-py3.10
Executable:     /home/veith/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my-other-directory-HASH-py3.10/bin/python
Valid:          True
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I don't even understand where poetry knows the current virtualenv from if I set the `cwd` keyword in the subprocess call.

Comment: I think you must unset the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable for the subprocess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poetry does not create a new venv if it detects, that the current environment is a venv. This is done by looking for the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable.

If you unset the variable for the subprocess, poetry will happily create a new venv for you.

E.g.:

```py
import os
import subprocess

other_directory = "/some/path"
current_env = os.environ.copy()

if "VIRTUAL_ENV" in current_env:
    del current_env["VIRTUAL_ENV"]

subprocess.run([f"cd {other_directory} && poetry install && poetry env info"], cwd=other_directory, shell=True, check=True, env=current_env)
```